# Ordering new Virtualization Hosts - Do I need a Raid controller if my storage is shared?

Tags: hardware-raid, host

I am planning to order some new servers. It crossed my mind that I can reduce my costs a bit if I do not order a raid controller.

The logic behind, is that my storage is on a shared storage server, so why should I bother with a raid on the host?  especially that I don't order any drives for it, as it will boot off USB sticks.

It reduces the cost by ~400$ but it might be more expensive in the future if I want to re-use this server for other usage.

Anyone has experience in such?

Should I invest the $'s to have a safe mind?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not even going to have disks in the machine I suggest not paying $400 for a RAID-controller you won't even use.

If you're gonna use the server for something else in the future, buy a RAID-card in the future instead :)